# Running jenkins-cli in bash

Tags: docker, jenkins, command-line-interface

HI i need too wright a docker script which downloads jenkins and jenkin-cli.jar from it. but im unable to run jar file from bash. MAy i know why? and solution for it?
 Here is my script

```
    FROM ubuntu:14.04
    RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get upgrade -y && \
    apt-get install -y  software-properties-common && \
    add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java -y && \
    apt-get update && \
    echo oracle-java7-installer shared/accepted-oracle-license-v1-1 select true | /usr/bin/debconf-set-selections && \
    apt-get install -f -y oracle-java8-installer && \
    apt install -y default-jre curl wget git nano; \
    apt-get clean


# Install dependencies
RUN apt-get -y update  && \
    apt-get -yqq --no-install-recommends install git bzip2 curl unzip && \
    apt-get update

ENV JAVA_HOME /usr
ENV PATH $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

# copy jenkins war file to the container
ADD http://mirrors.jenkins.io/war-stable/2.107.1/jenkins.war /opt/jenkins.war
RUN chmod 644 /opt/jenkins.war
ENV JENKINS_HOME /jenkins

# configure the container to run jenkins, mapping container port 8080 to that host port
RUN mkdir /jenkins/
RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.UpgradeWizard.state
RUN echo 2.107.1 > /jenkins/jenkins.install.InstallUtil.lastExecVersion
ENTRYPOINT ["nohup","java", "-jar", "/opt/jenkins.war"]
EXPOSE 8080
VOLUME /jenkins
#COPY jenkins-cli.jar /jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar

#jenkins-cli installation
ENV JENKINS_URL "http://192.168.99.100:8080/cli"
RUN curl --insecure -OL http://192.168.99.100:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar \
       --output jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar","-noCertificateCheck","-noKeyAuth"]
```

**Error:**

[image: NEW error]

**MY ASSUMPTION**
Enrytpoint  is conflicting
If any other problem let me know that and solution for that.

Comment: `RUN curl --insecure -OL http://192.168.99.100:8080/cli \
           --output jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar` there is no `/` before `jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar` here. Hope this is the error.

Comment: thank you @SVMadhavaReddy atleast it is accessible from bash, by doing ls im finding it, but its showing invalid or corrupt file (screen shot is updated in question)

Comment: can you able to login and delete the `/jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar`? If so please delete it once and re run it again.

Comment: yes im able to delete it, and i did and re run file but same error, also y am not getting that file in folder jenkins?????

Comment: You have got error in your curl url: corrected will be like `curl --insecure http://192.168.99.100:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar --output /jenkins/jenkins-cli.jar`

Comment: type `man curl` to know about the options. `-o` is represented as `--output` `-l` represented as `--list-only`. For [more info](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html)

Comment: now its not woking,
$ docker run -it --entrypoint /bin/bash f26dfa56742d
root@b46743cf4bb0:/# java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://192.168.99.100:8080/ help
Error: Unable to access jarfile jenkins-cli.jar

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169334/discussion-between-sv-madhava-reddy-and-hithesh).